# Visual Studio keep expanding things

Tags: visual-studio

- I collapse a project in Project Explorer. Save, close Visual Studio, reopen the solution, **everything** is expanded.
- I collapse a method, or a region, or a comment, or whatever other piece of code. Save, close Visual Studio, reopen the solution, reopen the file, **everything** is expanded.
- I collapse some XAML. Save, close Visual Studio, reopen the solution, reopen the file, **everything** is expanded.

At first I was using Visual Studio 2015 and I had not this problem. Then it started behaving this way. Then I **uninstalled** VS2015, and then installed VS2017.

It keeps doing it. It doesn't happens with all the solutions or projects, by the way, and it's not consistent. In some cases it only expands all projects in the Project Explorer, in other cases it expands everything.

Any idea? What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have check "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions)?

If it's on, Solution Explorer will expand folders.

Comment: That's the first thing that I disable every time I install a Visual Studio :-)